# Google Measurement Protocol for GA4 stopped recording or partially excludes data randomly

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I have reason to believe Google Analytics updated their algorithm to partially or entirely filter out events received via the measurement protocol on high traffic'd Properties.
I can send the same request to two environments ( except for the obvious credentials differentials ). Both Properties reveal via Debug View that they are successfully receiving these events and all values, but they are absent in RealTime View and from the Reports.

**High Traffic'd Property**

It will record,

- Device, UserAgent, EngagementTimeMSec, and PageReferrer 50% of the time.
- page_location was recorded 20% of the time.
- Session ID was recorded 10% of the time.
- All other property are ignored entirely.

**Low Traffic Property**

It records all attributes 100% of the time.

An example of the event that is sent :

```
{:client_id=>"1699346174.6829318294",
 :events=>
  [{:name=>"foo_bar",
    :params=>
     {:debug_mode=>1,
      :engagement_time_msec=>42,
      :page_location=>"/l/triptest?foo=bar",
      :page_referrer=>"mobile",
      :user_agent=>
       "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
      :session_id=>"1699349952",
      :device=>"Trip: Spaceship"}}]}
```

I can confirm we made zero changes to our Google Analytics Admin or Properties. And that the data became partially or entirely ignored as of September 22nd. Which leads me to believe that Google perhaps released an update that ended collection in whatever unique circumstance my data structure is in.

Both Properties High and Low are equal in all settings and are mirrors of each other except for the data stream ID's, API secrets, etc.

Can anyone determine if there is a missing or malformed attribute or if Google MP is known for filtering out events that otherwise successfully appear in Debug View?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Unless its in the change log I dont think there is anyway someone on SO can tell you either way if its been changed.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo If by looking at my example event, anyone can determine that there is a missing or malformed attribute **or** if Google MP is known for filtering out events that otherwise successfully appear in Debug View because of X,Y,Z.

Comment: But the event parms you are sending arent even valid [Events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference/events)  why would you expect them to be recorded in the first place?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Is there one in particular that does not seem valid? I've checked these a few times, and they all seem to be fine, both in key and value requisites. page_referrer, and page_location could, in theory, require a full URL which I attempted as well. But in the most minimal example of my error is that practically anything from Measurement Protocol, any event that is, doesn't pass parameters. And only records a fraction of the events sent. Thanks by the way for responding!

Comment: User_agent is definitely not valid and your not using one of the standard even names either

Comment: You can use any name, that's fine. They're then called custom events. And the user agent is valid. Even if I borrow the exact example of a user agent from their website, I have the same results. `"Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.0) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14"`. What's more is that even if I do use the pre-formatted events, such as `sign_up`, same thing. DebugView works. RealTime stats gets, 10% of of the hits, and none of them have data on them. Just the event name. Thank you again for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this does not work is severalfold:

In order of importance :

1. `custom_events` in GA4 depend on your explicitly defining **custom definition** for preset values `page_location` and `page_referrer` etc.
2. This only becomes a problem in high traffic'd properties, and only then when they have received X amount of traffic. So what would seemingly be normal will abruptly stop working eventually with no explanation whatsoever.
3. RealTime Events is in no way "real time". It can take 10 to 30+ minutes to receive data. If it goes beyond 30+ min. then it excludes it entirely. In addition, its results are filtered. In that, what it does receive data, only "some" of the actual content may or not be presented. In short, it does not represent what the API is receiving. Like GA4 as a whole, it should not be taken seriously. As the product is far below standard of what most analytic driven apps have to offer.